# Unity 5.6.0b3 CardboarHead Character Motion - App Crashing

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-project-tango, android-activityrecord

Creating a basic Cardboard Unity App following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-cardboard-integration

App loads fine on Unity and build. However, the app crashes without any errors when loading on the Project Tango Tablet.

Error message reads:

> Unfortunately, AppName has stopped.

- Android version 4.4.2
- Minimum API level - Android 4.2 'Jelly Bean'
- (API level 17) Runtime: Dalvik
- Unity 5.6.0b Personal
- Character Controller (Script)
- Tango Delta Pose Controller (Script) - Character Motion

> ./adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG

```
W/ActivityManager(  908): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4221d498 u0 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t53 f}
I/ActivityManager(  908): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +170ms
D/dalvikvm( 3940): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 20% free 3562K/4432K, paused 0ms+2ms, total 23ms
I/ActivityManager(  908): Process com.google.tango.prefab (pid 9525) has died.
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your scene, go to the Tango Manager object, and on the TangoUx script disable Draw Default UX Exceptions.